# Как добавить данные в связанные таблицы в symfony 2.8?

Tags: symfony2

Есть сущность "Организации" и сущность "Руководители организаций". При добавлении организации нужно одновременно добавлять руководителя, в одной форме или другим способом. Руководитель связан с организацией по id. Как это сделать в лучших практиках?

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="organization")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Organization
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */ 
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */       
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */       
    private $ur_address;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="Rukovoditel",
     *      mappedBy="id_organization",
     *      orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     */
    private $rukovoditel;     

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Organization
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add rukovoditel
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Rukovoditel $rukovoditel
     *
     * @return Organization
     */
    public function addRukovoditel(\AppBundle\Entity\Rukovoditel $rukovoditel)
    {
        $this->rukovoditel[] = $rukovoditel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove rukovoditel
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Rukovoditel $rukovoditel
     */
    public function removeRukovoditel(\AppBundle\Entity\Rukovoditel $rukovoditel)
    {
        $this->rukovoditel->removeElement($rukovoditel);
    }

    /**
     * Get rukovoditel
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRukovoditel()
    {
        return $this->rukovoditel;
    }

    /**
     * Set urAddress
     *
     * @param string $urAddress
     *
     * @return Organization
     */
    public function setUrAddress($urAddress)
    {
        $this->ur_address = $urAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get urAddress
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrAddress()
    {
        return $this->ur_address;
    }
}







<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="rukovoditel")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Rukovoditel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */         
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organization")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */        
    private $id_organization;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */       
    private $fio;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */       
    private $zvanie;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="RukovoditelZamestitel",
     *      mappedBy="id_rukovoditel",
     *      orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     */
    private $rukovoditel_zamestitel;     
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rukovoditel_zamestitel = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fio
     *
     * @param string $fio
     *
     * @return Rukovoditel
     */
    public function setFio($fio)
    {
        $this->fio = $fio;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fio
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFio()
    {
        return $this->fio;
    }

    /**
     * Set zvanie
     *
     * @param string $zvanie
     *
     * @return Rukovoditel
     */
    public function setZvanie($zvanie)
    {
        $this->zvanie = $zvanie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zvanie
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getZvanie()
    {
        return $this->zvanie;
    }

    /**
     * Set idOrganization
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Organization $idOrganization
     *
     * @return Rukovoditel
     */
    public function setIdOrganization(\AppBundle\Entity\Organization $idOrganization)
    {
        $this->id_organization = $idOrganization;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idOrganization
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Organization
     */
    public function getIdOrganization()
    {
        return $this->id_organization;
    }

    /**
     * Add rukovoditelZamestitel
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\RukovoditelZamestitel $rukovoditelZamestitel
     *
     * @return Rukovoditel
     */
    public function addRukovoditelZamestitel(\AppBundle\Entity\RukovoditelZamestitel $rukovoditelZamestitel)
    {
        $this->rukovoditel_zamestitel[] = $rukovoditelZamestitel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove rukovoditelZamestitel
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\RukovoditelZamestitel $rukovoditelZamestitel
     */
    public function removeRukovoditelZamestitel(\AppBundle\Entity\RukovoditelZamestitel $rukovoditelZamestitel)
    {
        $this->rukovoditel_zamestitel->removeElement($rukovoditelZamestitel);
    }

    /**
     * Get rukovoditelZamestitel
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRukovoditelZamestitel()
    {
        return $this->rukovoditel_zamestitel;
    }
}
```

Comment: У Вас в проекте в папке Entity должен быть файл сущности таблицы, которая отвечает за организации. Запостите сюда содержимое этого файла, тогда станет понятнее как добавить руководителя. Ну и файл сущности руководителя тоже не забудьте показать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Пишем примерно так (не ручаюсь за точность):

```
$rukovoditel = new Entity\Rukovoditel();
$rukovoditel->setFio('Иванов Иван Иванович')
$rukovoditel->setZvanie('Дежурный по стоянке торпедных катеров')
//задаем остальные свойства руководителя
$em->persist($rukovoditel);
$em->flush();

$organization = new Entity\Organization();
//задаем свойства организации
$organization->addRukovoditel($rukovoditel)
$em->persist($organization);
$em->flush();
```

Надеюсь ничего не напутал. С симфонией года два не работал.

Comment: Этот момент я понял. А как эти данные получить от пользователя?
Как в билдере форм работать с несколькими сущностями и потом их обрабатывать в контроллере? Или нужно по-другому решать?

Comment: Сущность руководителя можно построить отдельно, а потом внедрить ее в сущность организации уже в контроллере. Но я уже не помню все нюансы работы с билдером. Возможно это делается как-то иначе.

Comment: пока смог получить остальные данные через параметры запроса - $request->request->get('test'), а дальше как вы писали выше. Как сделать по методологии symfony...

Comment: Я вот думаю... У меня в проектах на Symfony были сущности с множеством связей. Причем эти связи пронизывали все сущности вдоль и поперек. Если бы я пытался вот так выстроить формы по каким-то правилам, то запутался бы, да и не смог бы построить формы так, как мне хочется. Поэтому я все это всегда разделял. Но я видел где-то в примерах построение связанных форм.