# Как получить данные из связанных сущностей symfony 2.8?

Tags: symfony2

Есть две сущности

Организация:

class Organization
{

```
private $id;

private $name;

private $ur_address;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="OrganizationObject",
 *      mappedBy="id_organization",
 *      orphanRemoval=true
*/
private $organizationObject;

public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function addOrganizationObject(\AppBundle\Entity\OrganizationObject $organizationObject)
{
    $this->organizationObject[] = $organizationObject;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove organizationObject
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\OrganizationObject $organizationObject
 */
public function removeOrganizationObject(\AppBundle\Entity\OrganizationObject $organizationObject)
{
    $this->organizationObject->removeElement($organizationObject);
}

/**
 * Get organizationObject
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getOrganizationObject()
{
    return $this->organizationObject;
}

/**
 * Set urAddress
 *
 * @param string $urAddress
 *
 * @return Organization
 */
public function setUrAddress($urAddress)
{
    $this->ur_address = $urAddress;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get urAddress
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUrAddress()
{
    return $this->ur_address;
}
```

}

Объекты Организации:

```
<?php
```

class OrganizationObject
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organization")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */       
private $id_organization;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */        
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */        
private $kolvo_sotrudnikov;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return OrganizationObject
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set kolvoSotrudnikov
 *
 * @param integer $kolvoSotrudnikov
 *
 * @return OrganizationObject
 */
public function setKolvoSotrudnikov($kolvoSotrudnikov)
{
    $this->kolvo_sotrudnikov = $kolvoSotrudnikov;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get kolvoSotrudnikov
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getKolvoSotrudnikov()
{
    return $this->kolvo_sotrudnikov;
}

/**
 * Set idOrganization
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Organization $idOrganization
 *
 * @return OrganizationObject
 */
public function setIdOrganization(\AppBundle\Entity\Organization $idOrganization)
{
    $this->id_organization = $idOrganization;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idOrganization
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Organization
 */
public function getIdOrganization()
{
    return $this->id_organization;
}
```

}

Допустим, что Организации добавлены. Теперь нужно добавить Объекты Организаций. Объекты Организаций связаны по id Организации. В форме нужно вывести список Организаций.
Как в форме вывести эти Организации в стиле symfony?

RukovoditelType.php

```
<?php
```

class RukovoditelType extends AbstractType
{

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('fio');
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Rukovoditel',
    ));
}
```

}

OrganizationType.php

```
<?php
```

class OrganizationType extends AbstractType
{

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', null, array('attr' => array('autofocus' => true),))
        ->add('ur_address', null, array())
        ->add('rukovoditel', CollectionType::class, array(
              'entry_type' => RukovoditelType::class));
        //->add('fio', CollectionType::class, array(
        //'entry_type' => RukovoditelType::class));
        //->add('rukovoditel', TextType::class, array(
        //'entry_type' => Rukovoditel::class
    //));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Organization',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'organization';
}
```

}

OrganizationController.php

```
<?php
```

class OrganizationController extends Controller{

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="organization_new")
*/    
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $organization = new Organization();
    $rukov = new Rukovoditel();

    $form = $this->createForm(new OrganizationType(), $organization);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        /*$rukov->setFio($request->request->get('fio'));
        $rukov->setZvanie($request->request->get('zvanie'));
        $rukov->setIdOrganization($organization);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($organization);
        $em->persist($rukov);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('main_index');
        */
    }

    return $this->render('organization/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

В форме вам может помочь [EntityType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

P.S. методы вида `setIdOrganization` не нужны, Doctrine сама правильно свяжет строки, если вы правильно выставите связь между сущностями.

Comment: Можете подробнее, лучше на примере или пояснить пример из приведенной вами ссылки, как составить билдер форм используя entityType ? 
Я добавил выше свой код, может на нем получиться объяснить?
Может еще поможете ответить на этот мой вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479909/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-symfony-2-8/479969?noredirect=1#comment550561_479969